# C: Is there a way to lower the speed of printf-outputs

Tags: c, printf, microcontroller

as said in the heading, is there a way to lower the speed of printf-outputs in C? Just like watching every character getting printed in particular (it does not have to be so slow, just so you understand what i mean).

The reason why i ask is:

I need to program a small microcontroller. But every 'printf' executed on it should be send back to the com1 port of the host. Everything works fine, I already buffered my printf so everything will be stored in a char-array with a finit size and this array will be sent back to com1 char by char. But because i don't know how many printfs there will be, and because of the limited memory of the μC, a size-limited array isn't the best solution. So my new attempt is to write directly to the send-register of the μC, which can only contain one char at a time until its sent. I do this via

```
setvbuf(stdout, LINFLEX_0.BDRL.B.DATA0, _IOFBF, 1);
```

where LINFLEX_0.BDRL.B.DATA0 represents the transmit-register. What I think what my problem is now: the printfs just overwrite the register to fast, so it has no time to send any char stored in it before it gets changed again. When sending char by char from the array, i wait until a data-transmission-flag is set:

```
//write character to transmit buffer
LINFLEX_0.BDRL.B.DATA0 = buffer[j];
// Wait for data transmission completed flag
while (1 != LINFLEX_0.UARTSR.B.DTF) {}  
// Clear DTF Flag
LINFLEX_0.UARTSR.R = 0x0002;
```

So the idea is to slower the speed the printfs processes every character, but feel free to comment if anyone has another idea.

Comment: How did your buffered technique work? Cant you repeat the logic here?

Comment: Printf uses putchar function so if you will write your own putchar function it will be possible

Comment: What uC are you using? Does it have DMA?

Comment: @JonnySchubert I already wrote my own printf and just replaced the output to the screen with the register writing as described above. The Problem is i can't override the standard printf in C with my own printf function. To DMA: yes, 32 eDMA channels. Im using the MPC5646c board

Comment: The standard printf function normally uses an abstract function to transfer a single char. This function can be overwritten by the user. The name is platform dependent. Here is an example for STM https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206113/how-do-i-use-the-printf-function-on-stm32

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya unfortunately not. At first i buffered my stdout with the sized array. After that I executed all the printfs, and as last I wrote every char of the array to the transmit-register (described above) via a for-loop

Comment: @drunkensponge *"via for loop"* -- and you didn't need any artificial delay in that loop either??? The original printf won't be any faster than a simple loop, so I assume the problem is rather another one. Possibly printf considers buffer size and discards any output not fitting into...

Comment: @Aconcagua The delay in the for-loop was a while-loop which does nothing until the data-transmit-flag was set. Besides that I transmitted the data AFTER all printfs were executed, so there was no need to be fast. Unfortunately i have no access to the code-segment where the printfs are called

Comment: MPC56 is hardly a "small microcontroller"... it is rather one of the most complex ones on the market.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with printf as such but with the underlying UART driver. That's what you'd have to tweak. If you are using Codewarrior for MPC56 you can actually view the source code for all of it: quite horrible code. Messing with it will only go bad - and apparently it doesn't seem to work well in the first place.

Using printf in these kind of embedded applications is overall a very bad idea, since the function is unsuitable for pretty much any purpose, UART communication in particular. The presence of printf is actually an indicator that a project has gone terribly wrong, quite possibly it has been hijacked by PC programmers. That's not really a programming problem, but a manager one.

Technically, the only sane thing to do here is to toss out all the crap from your project. That means everything remotely resembling stdio.h. Instead, write your own UART driver, based on the available Freescale examples. Make it work on bytes. This also enables you to add custom features such as "echo", where the MCU has to wait for a reply from the receiver. Or you could implement it with DMA if you just want to write data to a buffer and then forget all about it.